# Issue when trying to open modal div in angular cli

Tags: angular, angular-cli

**Error Details**

roleSaveModal.show is not a function. Issue comes when I click the button.

[image]

**Code**

```
<a (click)="showSaveRoleForm(roleSaveModal);">
    Click Me
</a>
```

**Controller Side**

```
export class RoleComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
    
    showSaveRoleForm(roleSaveModal: any) {
        roleSaveModal.show();
    }
    
}
```

**Modal Div**

```
<div class="modal fade" #roleSaveModal tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a more complete version of the code? at least in the code you posted, the controller (RoleComponent) does not have a roleSaveModal and it would not work

Comment: `roleSaveModal` is of type `any`, it is mentioned in the function arguments. roleSaveModal  is id of div. Modal div is already there in question.

Comment: What type of modal are you using? if you log the contents of roleSaveModal before the show what do you see?

Comment: I could see entire modal div in console.

Answer (score 0):

The [template variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) you are using does not attach to any special component here, so it is passing an [HTMLDivElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDivElement), which does not have a `show()` function.

It looks like you are maybe trying to use Bootstrap? If so you can set the show attribute of that div like so:

```
export class RoleComponent implements OnInit {

    show = false;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }
    
    showSaveRoleForm() {
        this.show = true;
    }
    
}

...

<a (click)="showSaveRoleForm()">
    Click Me
</a>
<div class="modal fade" [attr.data-show]="show" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this time there was no error, also, nothing popped up.

Comment: Cannot say for sure without fully knowing the libraries you may be using (Bootstrap CSS only vs Bootstrap + JQuery vs. ng-bootstrap), but I am guessing the confusion may be coming from how Bootstrap works with JQuery, where it exposes the JQuery method `show()`. My recommendation is when using Bootstrap with Angular, solely make use of the CSS. [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home) can help with some of the functionality as well.